# Can I use a single power supply to power a Raspberry Pi and some relays?

Tags: power-supply

I need to power a Raspberry Pi and some relays (that work with 5V). Would it be possible to use a single power supply for both? Because I will have a lot of relays, I can't use 5V Raspberry Pi pins to power them (current is limited by the polyfuse, so it won't be enough).

I would like to use this one: https://www.amazon.co.uk/sourcingmap-Switch-Power-Supply-Driver/dp/B019RNKK7I

Would be possible to connect a micro-USB cable to the power supply's V+ and V- to power the Raspberry Pi, and connect to the same V+ and V- to power the relays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be OK.

I have used similar power supply and they seem reasonably well regulated.

These power supplies are really designed to be built in to devices, and you should really use some kind of protection. The mains power connector is covered by an insulator, but this would not meet normal insulation standards for a stand alone unit.

Comment: Thanks. My question is if can I connect relays and RPi to the same V+ V- connections in the power supply.

Comment: @SergioViudes As I said "That should be OK". The rest was just additional comment.